# Getting a error when deleting a pdf file in Roxy Fileman

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects, nopcommerce, roxy-fileman

Is there a way to delete a file in Roxy Fileman, I keep on getting a error when I try to delete a pdf in Roxy Fileman, the delete folder is working fine just the file not want to delete.

I have been struggling to find a solution for two weeks, still this problem persist, Any help, suggestions would be much appreciated.

Hi yall,

Basically everything is working fine just not the deleteFile() the only thing that's giving me error, when Im I try to delete, its a javascript error Main.js the deleteFile() function needs to be corrected

I have updated the script

Please see code below, Thanks alot

Main.js

```js
$.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});
function selectFile(item){
  $('#pnlFileList li').removeClass('selected');
  $(item).prop('class', 'selected');
  var html = RoxyUtils.GetFilename($(item).attr('data-path'));
  html += ' ('+t('Size')+': '+RoxyUtils.FormatFileSize($(item).attr('data-size'));
  if($(item).attr('data-w') > 0)
    html += ', '+t('Dimensions')+':'+$(item).attr('data-w')+'x'+$(item).attr('data-h');
  html += ')';
  $('#pnlStatus').html(html);
}
var uploadFileList = new Array();
function showUploadList(files){
  var filesPane = $('#uploadFilesList');
  filesPane.html('');
  clearFileField();
  for(i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    filesPane.append('<div class="fileUpload"><div class="fileName">'+files[i].name+' ('+RoxyUtils.FormatFileSize(files[i].size)+')<span class="progressPercent"></span><div class="uploadProgress"><div class="stripes"></div></div></div><a class="removeUpload" onclick="removeUpload(' + i + ')"></a></div>');
  }
  if(files.length > 0)
    $('#btnUpload').button('enable');
  else
    $('#btnUpload').button('disable');
}
function listUploadFiles(files){
  if(!window.FileList) {
    $('#btnUpload').button('enable');
  }
  else if(files.length > 0) {
    uploadFileList = new Array();
    addUploadFiles(files);
  }
}
function addUploadFiles(files){
  for(i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    uploadFileList.push(files[i]);
  showUploadList(uploadFileList);
}
function removeUpload(i){
  var el = findUploadElement(i);
  el.remove();
  try{
    uploadFileList.splice(i, 1);
    showUploadList(uploadFileList);
  }
  catch(ex){
    //alert(ex); 
  }
}
function findUploadElement(i){
  return $('#uploadFilesList .fileUpload:eq(' + (i)+ ')');
} 
function updateUploadProgress(e, i){
  var el = findUploadElement(i);
  var percent = 99;
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    percent = Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
  }
  if(percent > 99)
    percent = 99;
  el.find('.uploadProgress').css('width', percent + '%');
  el.find('.progressPercent').html(' - ' + percent + '%');
}
function uploadComplete(e, i){
  uploadFinished(e, i, 'ok');
}
function uploadError(e, i){
  setUploadError(i);
  uploadFinished(e, i, 'error');
}
function setUploadError(i){
  var el = findUploadElement(i);
  el.find('.uploadProgress').css('width', '100%').addClass('uploadError').removeClass('uploadComplete');
  el.find('.progressPercent').html(' - <span class="error">' + t('E_UploadingFile')+'</span>');
}
function setUploadSuccess(i){
  var el = findUploadElement(i);
  el.find('.uploadProgress').css('width', '100%').removeClass('uploadError').addClass('uploadComplete');
  el.find('.progressPercent').html(' - 100%');
}
function uploadCanceled(e, i){
  uploadFinished(e, i, 'error');
}
function uploadFinished(e, i, res){
  var el = findUploadElement(i);
  var httpRes = null;
  try{
    httpRes = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);
  }
  catch(ex){}
  
  if((httpRes && httpRes.res == 'error') || res != 'ok'){
    res = 'error';
    setUploadError(i);
  }
  else{
    res = 'ok';
    setUploadSuccess(i)
  }
    
  el.attr('data-ulpoad', res);
  checkUploadResult();
}
function checkUploadResult(){
  var all = $('#uploadFilesList .fileUpload').length;
  var completed = $('#uploadFilesList .fileUpload[data-ulpoad]').length;
  var success = $('#uploadFilesList .fileUpload[data-ulpoad="ok"]').length;
  if(completed == all){
     //$('#uploadResult').html(success + ' files uploaded; '+(all - success)+' failed');
     uploadFileList = new Array();
     var d = Directory.Parse($('#hdDir').val());
     d.ListFiles(true);
     $('#btnUpload').button('disable');
  }
}
function fileUpload(f, i){
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var fData = new FormData();
  var el = findUploadElement(i);
  el.find('.removeUpload').remove();
  fData.append("action", 'upload');
  fData.append("method", 'ajax');
  fData.append("d", $('#hdDir').attr('value'));
  fData.append("files[]", f);
  http.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e){updateUploadProgress(e, i);}, false);
  http.addEventListener("load", function(e){uploadComplete(e, i);}, false);
  http.addEventListener("error", function(e){uploadError(e, i);}, false);
  http.addEventListener("abort", function(e){uploadCanceled(e, i);}, false);
  http.open("POST", RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD, true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
  http.send(fData);
}
function dropFiles(e, append){
  if(e && e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files){
    addFile();
    if(append)
      addUploadFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
    else
      listUploadFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
  }
  else
    addFile();
}
function clearFileField(selector){
  if(!selector)
    selector = '#fileUploads';
  try{
    $(selector).val('');
    $(selector).val(null);
  }
  catch(ex){}
}
function addFileClick(){
  $('#uploadResult').html('');
  showUploadList(new Array());
  addFile();
}
function addFile(){
  clickFirstOnEnter('dlgAddFile');
  $('#uploadResult').html('');
  clearFileField();
  var dialogButtons = {};
  dialogButtons[t('Upload')] = {id:'btnUpload', text: t('Upload'), disabled:true, click:function(){
    if(!$('#fileUploads').val() && (!uploadFileList || uploadFileList.length == 0))
      alert(t('E_SelectFiles'));
    else{
      if(!RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD){
        alert(t('E_ActionDisabled'));
        //$('#dlgAddFile').dialog('close');
      }
      else{
        if(window.FormData && window.XMLHttpRequest && window.FileList && uploadFileList && uploadFileList.length > 0){
          for(i = 0; i < uploadFileList.length; i++){
            fileUpload(uploadFileList[i], i);
          } 
        }
        else{
          document.forms['addfile'].action = RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD;
          document.forms['addfile'].submit();
        }
      }
    }
  }};
  
  dialogButtons[t('Cancel')] = function(){$('#dlgAddFile').dialog('close');};
  $('#dlgAddFile').dialog({title:t('T_AddFile'),modal:true,buttons:dialogButtons,width:400});
}
function fileUploaded(res){
  if(res.res == 'ok' && res.msg){
     $('#dlgAddFile').dialog('close');
     var d = Directory.Parse($('#hdDir').val());
     d.ListFiles(true);
     alert(res.msg);
  }
  else if(res.res == 'ok'){
     $('#dlgAddFile').dialog('close');
     var d = Directory.Parse($('#hdDir').val());
     d.ListFiles(true);
  }
  else
    alert(res.msg);
}
function renameDir(){
  var f = getSelectedDir();
  if(!f)
    return;
  if($('[data-path="'+f.fullPath+'"]').parents('li').length < 1){
     alert(t('E_CannotRenameRoot'));
     return;
  }
  clickFirstOnEnter('pnlDirName');
  $('#txtDirName').val(f.name);

  var dialogButtons = {};
  dialogButtons[t('RenameDir')] = function(){
    var newName = $.trim($('#txtDirName').val());
    if(!newName)
      alert(t('E_MissingDirName'));
    if(f.Rename(newName))
      $('#pnlDirName').dialog('close');
  };
  dialogButtons[t('Cancel')] = function(){$('#pnlDirName').dialog('close');};

  $('#pnlDirName').dialog({title:t('T_RenameDir'),modal:true,buttons:dialogButtons});
  RoxyUtils.SelectText('txtDirName', 0, new String(f.name).length);
}
function renameFile(){
  var f = getSelectedFile();
  if(!f)
    return;
  clickFirstOnEnter('pnlRenameFile');
  $('#txtFileName').val(f.name);

  var dialogButtons = {};
  dialogButtons[t('RenameFile')] = function(){
    var newName = $.trim($('#txtFileName').val());
    if(!newName)
      alert('Missing file name');
    else if(f.Rename(newName)){
      $('li[data-path="'+f.fullPath+'"] .name').text(newName);
      $('li[data-path="'+f.fullPath+'"]').attr('data-path', RoxyUtils.MakePath(f.path, newName));
      $('#pnlRenameFile').dialog('close');
    }
  };
  dialogButtons[t('Cancel')] = function(){$('#pnlRenameFile').dialog('close');};

  $('#pnlRenameFile').dialog({title:t('T_RenameFile'),modal:true,buttons:dialogButtons});
  if(f.name.lastIndexOf('.') > 0)
    RoxyUtils.SelectText('txtFileName', 0, f.name.lastIndexOf('.'));
}
function getSelectedFile(){
  var ret = null;
  if($('#pnlFileList .selected').length > 0)
    ret = new File($('#pnlFileList .selected').attr('data-path'));
  return ret;
}
function getSelectedDir(){
  var ret = null;
  if($('#pnlDirList .selected'))
    ret = Directory.Parse($('#pnlDirList .selected').closest('li').attr('data-path'));

  return ret;
}
function deleteDir(path){
  var d = null;
  if(path)
    d = Directory.Parse(path);
  else
    d = getSelectedDir();

  if(d && confirm(t('Q_DeleteFolder'))){
    d.Delete();
  }
}
function deleteFile(){
  var f = getSelectedFile();
  if(f && confirm(t('Q_DeleteFile'))){
    f.Delete();
  }
}
function previewFile(){
  var f = getSelectedFile();
  if(f){
    window.open(f.fullPath);
  }
}
function downloadFile(){
  var f = getSelectedFile();
  if(f && RoxyFilemanConf.DOWNLOAD){
    var url = RoxyUtils.AddParam(RoxyFilemanConf.DOWNLOAD, 'f', f.fullPath);
    window.frames['frmUploadFile'].location.href = url;
  }
  else if(!RoxyFilemanConf.DOWNLOAD)
    alert(t('E_ActionDisabled'));
}
function downloadDir(){
  var d = getSelectedDir();
  if(d && RoxyFilemanConf.DOWNLOADDIR){
    var url = RoxyUtils.AddParam(RoxyFilemanConf.DOWNLOADDIR, 'd', d.fullPath);
    window.frames['frmUploadFile'].location.href = url;
  }
  else if(!RoxyFilemanConf.DOWNLOAD)
    alert(t('E_ActionDisabled'));
}
function closeMenus(el){
  if(!el || el == 'dir')
    $('#menuDir').fadeOut();
  if(!el || el == 'file')
    $('#menuFile').fadeOut();
}
function selectFirst(){
  var item = $('#pnlDirList li:first').children('div').first();
  if(item.length > 0)
    selectDir(item);
  else
    window.setTimeout('selectFirst()', 300);
}
function tooltipContent(){
  if($('#menuFile').is(':visible'))
    return '';
  var html = '';
  var f = File.Parse($(this).attr('data-path'));
  if($('#hdViewType').val() == 'thumb' && f.IsImage()){
    html = f.fullPath+'<br><span class="filesize">'+t('Size')+': '+RoxyUtils.FormatFileSize(f.size) + ' '+t('Dimensions')+': '+f.width+'x'+f.height+'</span>';
  }
  else if(f.IsImage()){
    if(RoxyFilemanConf.GENERATETHUMB){
      imgUrl = RoxyUtils.AddParam(RoxyFilemanConf.GENERATETHUMB, 'f', f.fullPath);
      imgUrl = RoxyUtils.AddParam(imgUrl, 'width', RoxyFilemanConf.PREVIEW_THUMB_WIDTH);
      imgUrl = RoxyUtils.AddParam(imgUrl, 'height', RoxyFilemanConf.PREVIEW_THUMB_HEIGHT);
    }
    else
      imgUrl = f.fullPath;
    html = '<img src="'+imgUrl+'" class="imgPreview"><br>'+f.name+' <br><span class="filesize">'+t('Size')+': '+RoxyUtils.FormatFileSize(f.size) + ' '+t('Dimensions')+': '+f.width+'x'+f.height+'</span>';
  }
  else
    html = f.fullPath+' <span class="filesize">'+t('Size')+': '+RoxyUtils.FormatFileSize(f.size) + '</span>';
  return html;
}
function filterFiles(){
  var str = $('#txtSearch').val();
  $('#pnlSearchNoFiles').hide();
  if($('#pnlFileList li').length == 0)
    return;
  if(!str){
    $('#pnlFileList li').show();
    return;
  }
  var i = 0;
  $('#pnlFileList li').each(function(){
      var name = $(this).children('.name').text();
      if(name.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) > -1){
        i++;
        $(this).show();
      }
      else{
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).hide();
      }
  });
  if(i == 0)
    $('#pnlSearchNoFiles').show();
}
function sortFiles(){
  var d = getSelectedDir();
  if(!d)
    return;
  d.ListFiles();
  filterFiles();
  switchView($('#hdViewType').val());
}
function switchView(t){
  if(t == $('#hdViewType').val())
    return;
  if(!t)
    t = $('#hdViewType').val();
  $('.btnView').removeClass('selected');
  if(t == 'thumb'){
    $('#pnlFileList .icon').attr('src', 'images/blank.gif');
    $('#pnlFileList').addClass('thumbView');
    if($('#dynStyle').length == 0){
      $('head').append('<style id="dynStyle" />');
      var rules = 'ul#pnlFileList.thumbView li{width:'+RoxyFilemanConf.THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH+'px;}';
      rules += 'ul#pnlFileList.thumbView li{height:'+(parseInt(RoxyFilemanConf.THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT) + 20)+'px;}';
      rules += 'ul#pnlFileList.thumbView .icon{width:'+RoxyFilemanConf.THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH+'px;}';
      rules += 'ul#pnlFileList.thumbView .icon{height:'+RoxyFilemanConf.THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT+'px;}';
      $('#dynStyle').html(rules);
    }
    $('#pnlFileList li').each(function(){
      
      //$('ul#pnlFileList.thumbView li').css('width', RoxyFilemanConf.THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH + 'px');
      //$('ul#pnlFileList.thumbView li').css('height', (parseInt(RoxyFilemanConf.THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT) + 20) + 'px');
      //$('ul#pnlFileList.thumbView .icon').css('width', RoxyFilemanConf.THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH + 'px');
      //$('ul#pnlFileList.thumbView .icon').css('height', RoxyFilemanConf.THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT + 'px');
      var imgUrl = $(this).attr('data-icon-big');
      if(RoxyFilemanConf.GENERATETHUMB && RoxyUtils.IsImage($(this).attr('data-path'))){
        imgUrl = RoxyUtils.AddParam(RoxyFilemanConf.GENERATETHUMB, 'f', imgUrl);
        imgUrl = RoxyUtils.AddParam(imgUrl, 'width', RoxyFilemanConf.THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH);
        imgUrl = RoxyUtils.AddParam(imgUrl, 'height', RoxyFilemanConf.THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT);
      }
      $(this).children('.icon').css('background-image', 'url('+imgUrl+')');
      $(this).tooltip('option', 'show', {delay:50});
    });
    $('#btnThumbView').addClass('selected');
  }
  else{
    $('#pnlFileList').removeClass('thumbView');
    $('#pnlFileList li').each(function(){
      $(this).children('.icon').css('background-image','').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-icon'));
      $(this).tooltip('option', 'show', {delay:500});
    });
    $('#btnListView').addClass('selected');
  }
  $('#hdViewType').val(t);
  RoxyUtils.SetCookie('roxyview', t, 10);
}
var clipBoard = null;
function Clipboard(a, obj){
  this.action = a;
  this.obj = obj;
}
function cutDir(){
  var d = getSelectedDir();
  if(d){
    setClipboard('cut', d);
    d.GetElement().addClass('pale');
  }
}
function copyDir(){
  var d = getSelectedDir();
  if(d){
    setClipboard('copy', d);
  }
}
function cutFile(){
  var f = getSelectedFile();
  if(f){
    setClipboard('cut', f);
    f.GetElement().addClass('pale');
  }
}
function copyFile(){
  var f = getSelectedFile();
  if(f){
    setClipboard('copy', f);
  }
}
function pasteToFiles(e, el){
  if($(el).hasClass('pale')){
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
  var d = getSelectedDir();
  if(!d)
    d = Directory.Parse($('#pnlDirList li:first').children('div').first());
  if(d && clipBoard && clipBoard.obj){
    if(clipBoard.action == 'copy')
      clipBoard.obj.Copy(d.fullPath);
    else{
      clipBoard.obj.Move(d.fullPath);
      clearClipboard();
    }
  }
  return true;
}
function pasteToDirs(e, el){
  if($(el).hasClass('pale')){
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
  var d = getSelectedDir();
  if(!d)
    d = Directory.Parse($('#pnlDirList li:first').children('div').first());
  if(clipBoard && d){
    if(clipBoard.action == 'copy')
      clipBoard.obj.Copy(d.fullPath);
    else{
      clipBoard.obj.Move(d.fullPath);
      clearClipboard();
      d.ListFiles(true);
    }
  }
  else
    alert('error');
  return true;
}
function clearClipboard(){
  $('#pnlDirList li').removeClass('pale');
  $('#pnlFileList li').removeClass('pale');
  clipBoard = null;
  $('.paste').addClass('pale');
}
function setClipboard(a, obj){
  clearClipboard();
  if(obj){
    clipBoard = new Clipboard(a, obj);
    $('.paste').removeClass('pale');
  }
}
function ResizeLists(){
  var tmp = $(window).innerHeight() - $('#fileActions .actions').outerHeight() - $('.bottomLine').outerHeight();
  $('.scrollPane').css('height', tmp);
}
function removeDisabledActions(){
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.CREATEDIR == ''){
    $('#mnuCreateDir').next().remove();
    $('#mnuCreateDir').remove();
    $('#btnAddDir').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.DELETEDIR == ''){
    $('#mnuDeleteDir').prev().remove();
    $('#mnuDeleteDir').remove();
    $('#btnDeleteDir').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.MOVEDIR == ''){
    $('#mnuDirCut').next().remove();
    $('#mnuDirCut').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.COPYDIR == ''){
    $('#mnuDirCopy').next().remove();
    $('#mnuDirCopy').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.COPYDIR == '' && RoxyFilemanConf.MOVEDIR == ''){
    $('#mnuDirPaste').next().remove();
    $('#mnuDirPaste').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.RENAMEDIR == ''){
    $('#mnuRenameDir').next().remove();
    $('#mnuRenameDir').remove();
    $('#btnRenameDir').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD == ''){
    $('#btnAddFile').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.DOWNLOAD == ''){
    $('#mnuDownload').next().remove();
    $('#mnuDownload').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.DOWNLOADDIR == ''){
    $('#mnuDownloadDir').next().remove();
    $('#mnuDownloadDir').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.DELETEFILE == ''){
    $('#mnuDeleteFile').prev().remove();
    $('#mnuDeleteFile').remove();
    $('#btnDeleteFile').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.MOVEFILE == ''){
    $('#mnuFileCut').next().remove();
    $('#mnuFileCut').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.COPYFILE == ''){
    $('#mnuFileCopy').next().remove();
    $('#mnuFileCopy').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.COPYFILE == '' && RoxyFilemanConf.MOVEFILE == ''){
    $('#mnuFilePaste').next().remove();
    $('#mnuFilePaste').remove();
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.RENAMEFILE == ''){
    $('#mnuRenameFile').next().remove();
    $('#mnuRenameFile').remove();
    $('#btnRenameFile').remove();
  }
}
function getPreselectedFile(){
  var filePath = RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('selected');
  if(!filePath){
    switch(getFilemanIntegration()){
      case 'ckeditor':
        try{
          var dialog = window.opener.CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
          filePath = dialog.getValueOf('info', (dialog.getName() == 'link'?'url':'txtUrl'));
        }
        catch(ex){}
      break;
      case 'tinymce3':
        try{
          var win = tinyMCEPopup.getWindowArg("window");
          filePath = win.document.getElementById(tinyMCEPopup.getWindowArg("input")).value;
          if(filePath.indexOf('..') == 0)
            filePath = filePath.substr(2);
        }
        catch(ex){}
      break;
      case 'tinymce4':
        try{
          var win = (window.opener?window.opener:window.parent);
          filePath = win.document.getElementById(RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('input')).value;
          if(filePath.indexOf('..') == 0)
            filePath = filePath.substr(2);
        }
        catch(ex){}
      break;
      default:
        filePath = GetSelectedValue();     
      break;
    }
  }
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.RETURN_URL_PREFIX){
    var prefix = RoxyFilemanConf.RETURN_URL_PREFIX;
    if(filePath.indexOf(prefix) == 0){
      if(prefix.substr(-1) == '/')
        prefix = prefix.substr(0, prefix.length - 1);
      filePath = filePath.substr(prefix.length);
    }
  }
  
  return filePath;
}
function initSelection(filePath){
  var hasSelection = false, fileSelected = true;
  if(!filePath)
    filePath = getPreselectedFile();
  if(!filePath && RoxyUtils.ToBool(RoxyFilemanConf.OPEN_LAST_DIR)){
    filePath = getLastDir();
    fileSelected = false;
  }
  if(filePath){
    var p = (fileSelected? RoxyUtils.GetPath(filePath): filePath);
    var d = tmp = Directory.Parse(p);
    do{
      if(tmp){
        tmp.Expand(true);
        hasSelection = true; 
      }
      tmp = Directory.Parse(tmp.path);
    }while(tmp);
    
    if(d){
      d.Select(filePath);
      hasSelection = true; 
    }
  }
  if(!hasSelection)
    selectFirst();
}
$(function(){
  RoxyUtils.LoadConfig();
  var d = new Directory();
  d.LoadAll();
  $('#wraper').show();
  
  window.setTimeout('initSelection()', 100);

  RoxyUtils.Translate();
  $('body').click(function(){
    closeMenus();
  });
  
  var viewType = RoxyUtils.GetCookie('roxyview');
  if(!viewType)
    viewType = RoxyFilemanConf.DEFAULTVIEW;
  if(viewType)
    switchView(viewType);
    
  ResizeLists();
  $(".actions input").tooltip({track: true});
  $( window ).resize(ResizeLists);
  
  document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};
  removeDisabledActions();
  $('#copyYear').html(new Date().getFullYear());
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD && RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD != ''){
    var dropZone = document.getElementById('fileActions');
    dropZone.ondragover = function () { return false; };
    dropZone.ondragend = function () { return false; };
    dropZone.ondrop = function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      dropFiles(e);
    };
    
    dropZone = document.getElementById('dlgAddFile');
    dropZone.ondragover = function () { return false; };
    dropZone.ondragend = function () { return false; };
    dropZone.ondrop = function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      dropFiles(e, true);
    };
  }
  
  if(getFilemanIntegration() == 'tinymce3'){
    try {
      $('body').append('<script src="js/tiny_mce_popup.js"><\/script>');
    }
    catch(ex){}
  }
});
function getFilemanIntegration(){
  var integration = RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('integration');
  if(!integration)
    integration = RoxyFilemanConf.INTEGRATION;
    
  return integration.toLowerCase();
}
function setFile(){
  var f = getSelectedFile();
  if(!f){
    alert(t('E_NoFileSelected'));
    return;
  }
  var insertPath = f.fullPath;
  if(RoxyFilemanConf.RETURN_URL_PREFIX){
    var prefix = RoxyFilemanConf.RETURN_URL_PREFIX;
    if(prefix.substr(-1) == '/')
      prefix = prefix.substr(0, prefix.length - 1);
    insertPath = prefix + (insertPath.substr(0, 1) != '/'? '/': '') + insertPath;
  }
  switch(getFilemanIntegration()){
      case 'ckeditor':
      window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('CKEditorFuncNum'), insertPath);
      self.close();
    break;
    case 'tinymce3':
      var win = tinyMCEPopup.getWindowArg("window");
      win.document.getElementById(tinyMCEPopup.getWindowArg("input")).value = insertPath;
      if (typeof(win.ImageDialog) != "undefined") {
          if (win.ImageDialog.getImageData)
              win.ImageDialog.getImageData();

          if (win.ImageDialog.showPreviewImage)
              win.ImageDialog.showPreviewImage(insertPath);
      }
      tinyMCEPopup.close();
    break;
    case 'tinymce4':
      var win = (window.opener?window.opener:window.parent);
      win.document.getElementById(RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('input')).value = insertPath;
      if (typeof(win.ImageDialog) != "undefined") {
          if (win.ImageDialog.getImageData)
              win.ImageDialog.getImageData();
          if (win.ImageDialog.showPreviewImage)
              win.ImageDialog.showPreviewImage(insertPath);
      }
      win.tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
    break;
    default:
      FileSelected(f);
    break;
  }
}
```

Below is the error I'm getting in Nopcommerce roxyFileman

```js
jquery-migrate.js:69 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2
plugin.min.js:9 Text color plugin is now built in to the core editor, please remove it from your editor configuration
(anonymous) @ plugin.min.js:9
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:51848/lib_npm/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:51848/lib_npm/admin-lte/js/adminlte.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:51848/lib_npm/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:51848/lib_npm/fine-uploader/jquery.fine-uploader/jquery.fine-uploader.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:51848/lib_npm/admin-lte/css/adminlte.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:51848/lib_npm/fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

Comment: I don't know anything about roxy fileman, so I will not be able to help anyway. But for others to do it I think they will need more info on the kind of error you're experiencing. Is it a javascript message? is it a .net message in the nopcommerce's log? Has it any message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know who need this, I found the solution I was using NopCommerce 4.40.3 version, upgrade Nopcommerce to its latest version then the delete pdf etc. and all functions will work in roxy Fileman.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).